# Windows Azure Pricing precisions

Tags: asp.net, windows, azure

I am trying to estimate the cost of the development of a project on Windows Azure. But some stats are a bit vague. Here are my questions:

**Storage**
How can you calculate/estimate your number of storage transactions. Let's take an example, if one user downloads one file of 1Mo, how many transaction(s) ?

**Web and Worker Role Instances**
If you have a Web role (staging) and you deactivated it, I mean, his status is stopped. Do you pay for it ? Do you just need to stop it or delete the entire hosted service.

**Bandwidth**
How can you estimate your bandwidth.

(Maybe others questions will come after)

Thanks a lot for your answers !

Comment: not sure, this question belongs here

Comment: About roles - you'll still pay for role if it's just stopped, because resources for it are still reserved. You'll have to delete it.

Comment: "one file of 1Mo" - what do you mean? :) Access to storage is provided by REST service. Each call is a transaction for which you'll pay. For example: check if file exists, get file = 2 transactions.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answers, I think that the link posted by Sandrino is very good !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Storage**: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/07/09/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity.aspx

- When uploading a blob greater than 32 Mbytes, the storage client library will break it into 4 Mbyte blocks by default. The block size can be changed by setting the CloudBlobClient.WriteBlockSizeInBytes field. When uploading a blob larger than 32MBs the client library will upload each block as a separate PutBlock REST request and then commit all of the blocks at the end with a PutBlockList. Each PutBlock will count as 1 transaction, and the final PutBlockList will also count as 1 transaction.
- A single GetBlob request to the blob service = 1 transaction
- PutBlob    with 1 request to the blob service = 1 transaction
- Large blob upload that results in 100 requests via PutBlock, and then 1 PutBlockList
  for commit = 101 transactions
- Listing through a lot of blobs using 5 requests total (due to 4 continuation markers) = 5 transactions

**Web and Worker Role Instances**: Even if these instances are stopped, the resources will still be reserved for you and you'll keep paying. To stop paying, you'll need to decrease the number of instances or remove the hosted service.

**Bandwidth**: Estimations are always hard, but you'll need to take into account:

- The kind of data you'll be transferring
- Is the data compressed or not?
- How many (active) users do you have?
- Are you also transferring to North America and Europe? Or to other locations (these are more expensive!)
- Ingress is free and communication within the same datacenter is free. You only pay for data leaving the datacenter.

Answer (score 2):

Great answer by @Sandrino. Let me add a few more points of interest.

- Storage transaction pricing just dropped in price 10x last week, now at a penny per 100,000 transactions. The cost of transactions is really going to be insignificant compared to cost of compute and storage. To put this in perspective: Imagine a 100MB file with 4MB blocks being uploaded every second of the day. With 4 transactions for the file upload: (4x60x60x24x30) / 100,000 = 103 pennies.
- When it comes to shutting down a given role: Let's say you have a web role, along with a particular worker role that does nightly processing, and you only need the worker role for, say, one hour. During that one hour, you scale to some number of instances. At the end of the hour, you can *not* reduce that role to zero instances; the minimum is one instance per role. If you have a pattern like this, you're better off putting your nightly processing into a separate deployment (basically its own service). Then each night, you create a new deployment on the "nightly service" - let it run until all the work is done, then delete the deployment.
- If compute cost becomes heavy for you, and you have several roles (such as the web + worker example I just gave), you could combine functionality into a single role. These *roles* are essentially Windows 2008 server VMs, so there's nothing stopping you from creating multiple threads, launching processes, etc. Running everything in a single role has some scaling limitations (e.g. your background processing could starve the website of cpu during that one hour of processing), but you could always split your code up into separate roles in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also like to add that if you are running Virtual Machine instances rather than Service instances your VMS are hosted in blob storage.

This could mean that normal operating system disk i/o could cost you money.

> Compute hours do not include any Windows Azure Storage costs associated with the image running in Windows Azure Virtual Machines. These costs are billed separately.

reference : http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/

Not sure if there are any MS folks that will read this, but they could clear it up.

**would have added it as a comment, but feel its important enough to be an answer on its own